# Advanced data wrangling: how to deal with weird formatting and blanks in historical excel dataset with R

Tags: r, excel, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have inherited a 20 year study with over 100 sampling sites, with multiple plots within a site. Each site was entered into its own Excel file, with a new tab for each year of sampling. There is some header data that needs to be brought into the dataframe. Additionally, rather than entering data that repeats (eg, multiple observations for a single date or time period) they just left those cells blank. Here is a toy example:

```
data1<-structure(list(X = c("", "", "", "Year", "Plot number 1", "", 
                            "", "", "", "10 mins", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                            "", "Plot number 2", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "10 mins", 
                            "", ""), X.1 = c("", "", "", "2010", "DateJulian", "141", "", 
                                             "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Date - Julian", 
                                             "141", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Rocky.Ridge = c("Site B", 
                                                                                                                 "6 plots", "", "", "Species Code", "BBBB", "DDDD", "CCCC", "BBBB", 
                                                                                                                 "AAAA", "DDDD", "BBBB", "AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBB", "BBBB", "DDDD", 
                                                                                                                 "AAAA", "DDDD", "CCCC", "", "Species Code", "BBBB", "DDDD", "BBBB", 
                                                                                                                 "AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBB", "DDDD", "CCCC", "BBBB", "DDDD", "AAAA", 
                                                                                                                 "DDDD"), X.2 = c("", "", "", "", "audio", "2", "", "", "2", "1", 
                                                                                                                                  "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "", "2", "1", "", "audio", 
                                                                                                                                  "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "", "", "1", "1", "", "2"), X.3 = c("", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    "spring summer", "", "", "visual", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "", "", "visual", "1", "", "", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    "", "", "", "1", "1", "", "", "1", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -34L))
```

I am looking for a way to format these data so they are arranged in a single table like so:

```
data_clean<-structure(list(Study.Area = c("Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", 
                                          "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", 
                                          "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", 
                                          "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", 
                                          "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", 
                                          "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge", "Rocky Ridge"), 
                           Site = c("Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", 
                                    "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", 
                                    "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", 
                                    "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", 
                                    "Site B", "Site B", "Site B", "Site B"), Year = c(2010L, 
                                                                                      2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                                                                      2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                                                                      2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), 
                           Plot.number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L), DateJulian = c(141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 
                                                               141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 
                                                               141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L
                                           ), Time = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                                       10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                       5L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Species.Code = c("BBBB", "DDDD", "CCCC", 
                                                                                            "BBBB", "AAAA", "DDDD", "BBBB", "AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBB", "BBBB", 
                                                                                            "DDDD", "AAAA", "DDDD", "CCCC", "BBBB", "DDDD", "BBBB", "AAAA", 
                                                                                            "BBBB", "BBBB", "DDDD", "CCCC", "BBBB", "DDDD", "AAAA", "DDDD"
                                                       ), audio = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                    2L), visual = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                    0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

I would like to do this in R, but I am not sure there is any way to reasonably automate this, or if I am going to have to manually fill in the values that were not "filled down" in excel-speak. I have tried playing in the tidyverse, but haven't found a fill down feature or a way to "move" data from the header to the dataframe. Any help- even if it is just to say that I am better off re-entering the data- is appreciated.

Edited because I forgot to explain one more thing: there are two sampling time periods in each survey. The first 5 minutes is not specified in the data in any way except that it includes all the observations that occur before the row that has "10min" in it. Every observation after that row is in the 10min interval until the next plot. The number of observations that occur in each time period are not predictable across sites/plots. I can't believe how fast someone figured out the first part, I have been struggling with this for a very long, so I am hopeful that this issue can be addressed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add time based on the logic described in your edit.

Comment: Thank you! I am working through this slowly, line by line so I can modify for my dataset, but you have saved me so much time!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea with a problem like this is to extract all of your values from the "header" into columns, and essentially reconstruct a rectangular data frame. Before we remove the extra header rows, I reference them by position and create new columns for them. Once we have all the header stuff in columns, we can use `fill()` to complete the columns and then filter off the header/label rows. Note that `fill()` requires `NA` values rather than empty strings `""` to work, which is why for `DateJulian` I use `na_if`.

If the location of things like Study Area are not consistent between the files, you can use Regex or string logic to find those values rather than just looking for a value in the same position each time.

Edit: based on OP's edit, updated to add logic for the `Time` column. When column `X` contains the word "Plot" we know `Time = 5` and when `X` contains 10 we set `Time = 10` we can then `fill()` it down the same as we do with the other values.

```
library(tidyverse)

data1 %>% 
mutate(
    Study.Area = gsub("\\.", " ",names(.)[3]), 
    Site = .[1,3], 
    Year = .[4,2],
    Species.Code = .[,3],
    audio = X.2, 
    visual = X.3, 
    DateJulian = na_if(X.1,""), 
    Plot = ifelse(grepl("Plot", X), X, NA),
    Time = case_when(
            grepl("Plot", X) ~ 5,
            grepl("10", X) ~ 10
        )
    ) %>% 
fill(Plot, DateJulian, Time) %>% 
filter(!grepl("Plot number", X), !is.na(Plot)) %>% 
select(-starts_with("X")) %>%
select(-1)


    Study.Area   Site Year Species.Code audio visual DateJulian          Plot Time
1  Rocky Ridge Site B 2010         BBBB     2      1        141 Plot number 1    5
2  Rocky Ridge Site B 2010         DDDD            1        141 Plot number 1    5
3  Rocky Ridge Site B 2010         CCCC            1        141 Plot number 1    5
4  Rocky Ridge Site B 2010         BBBB     2               141 Plot number 1    5
5  Rocky Ridge Site B 2010         AAAA     1               141 Plot number 1   10
6  Rocky Ridge Site B 2010         DDDD     2               141 Plot number 1   10
7  Rocky Ridge Site B 2010         BBBB     3               141 Plot number 1   10
```